# How can I delete/update multiple entrys with WHERE and a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I delete/update multiple entrys with WHERE and a subquery?

```
DELETE FROM photos
WHERE user_id = (SELECT id FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin")
```

If there is only one id as a result of the subquery it works but for multiple it doesn't. Multiple IDs should behave as if they were "1 OR 2 OR 3 OR ..."

The error I get in this case:

> SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more
> than 1 row (SQL: DELETE FROM photos WHERE photos.user_id = (SELECT id
> FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
DELETE FROM photos WHERE user_id=ANY(SELECT id FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WHERE IN`

```sql
DELETE FROM photos
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin")
```

Comment: This would be the canonical solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends al little on the numbers

If the numbers are huge of users, you need to join the id as table

```
DELETE FROM photos
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin")
```

so it would be like

```
DELETE photos
FROM photos
INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM users WHERE city = "Berlin") u1 ON u1.id = photos.user_id
```